# Error: cast to smaller integer type 'int' from 'string' when doing `islower`

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);
int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
    if (score1 > score2) {
        printf("The winner is Player 1!");
    }
    else if (score1 < score2) {
        printf("The winner is Player 2!");
    }
    else {
        printf("Both players have the same score, so it's a draw!");
    }

}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i == strlen(word); i++) {
        if (islower(word)) {
            word = toupper(word);
        }
        string letter = word[i];
        int first_score[i] = POINTS(letter);
        for (int j = 0; j == strlen(first_score); i++) {
            sum = sum + first_score[j];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing the second lab of the cs50 course and this gives me that error when using the islower function, why is that? supposedly the 'word' is a string, so do I have to use the ASCII numbers?

Comment: Aside: Does ```string``` stand for a ```char *``` in your code?

Comment: @Haris it supposedly stands for a string

Comment: There can be no clear answer without knowing what's in `cs50.h` - I'm guessing the `string` type is defined there. If it's a typedef'd struct, that could be one cause of the issue.

Comment: @Shawn `string` is CS50's `typedef char *string` hide-the-pointer-for-even-more-confusion abomination.

Comment: Aside: it's not really necessary to test `islower(word[i])`, since `toupper` returns its argument unless its argument represents a lower-case letter. See [the manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/toupper.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. `islower(int ch), toupper(int ch)` expects an `int`.  `word` is a pointer, thus `if (islower(word)) {` is a problem.

Instead code should de-reference the pointer

2. `for (int i = 0; i == strlen(word); i++) {` is weak as `strlen()` is called many times when only detection of a *null character* is needed.
3. `tolower(word[i])` is a problem when `word[i] < 0`.  Best to access the string as `unsigned char`.
4. `POINTS(letter);` fails as `POINTS` is an array.    Care should be applied to insure the array is zero-base accessed and within range.
5. `if` not needed before calling `toupper()`.

---

```
// Code could use a type narrower than `int` here.
unsigned char POINTS[] = { //
    1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, //
    5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, //
    1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word) {
  // Access data as if unsigned char
  const unsigned char *uword = (const unsigned char *) string;
  int sum = 0;

  while (*uword) {
    if (isalpha(*uword)) {
      unsigned char ch_index = toupper(*uword) - 'A';
      if (ch_index < sizeof POINTS / sizeof POINTS[0]) {
        sum += POINTS[ch_index];
      }
    }
    uword++'
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Note: `toupper(*uword) - 'A'` only certainly works well with ASCII.